# Fetch data from 3 dependant table in Laravel (4.2) ORM

Tags: laravel-4, orm, data-retrieval

I want to retrieve data from 3 dependent tables.
Like: 
"Category" table contains some packages in "package" table and "package" table contains some products in "product" table.

In category Class I have:

```
public function relatedPackage() {
    return $this->hasMany('Package');
}
```

And retrieving data to display:

```
$_subcategories = Category::find($id)->with('relatedPackage')->get();
```

Till this I get categories>packages

But I want to get categories>packages>products

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
    public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany('Product');
    }
```

in your Package model.

Than you can call

```
$_subcategories = Category::find($id)->with('relatedPackage')->with('relatedPackage.products')->get();
```